# Good coding practice: Using a function call within the parameter list of another function call?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Let's say I have web page (built on MVC 4 using VB.Net) displaying data which a user may edit by clicking on the edit link.  This link will route to the `Edit` function by passing the `id` of the related data fields.

To display my edit page, I will grab the data, map it to a model, and pass it to the View.  We'll call my mapping function `Map2Model` which accepts the Entity Framework Model & returns the Model and the data access function `GetData` which returns the Entity Framework Model. `GetData` accepts the `id` of the data, and `userid`. We'll be using `SimpleMembership` for user authentication. Is it considered bad practice to do the following (call a function within the parameter list of another function call:

```
Function Edit(ByVal id as Integer) as ActionResult
    Dim Model2Edit = Map2Model(GetData(id, WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)))
    Return View(Model2Edit)
End Function
```

VS. (declaring variables first)

```
Function Edit(ByVal id as Integer) as ActionResult
    Dim TheData as New EntityModel
    Dim UserID as Integer
    Dim Model2Edit as New Model

    UserID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)
    TheData = GetData(id, UserID)
    Model2Edit = Map2Model(TheData)

    Return View(Model2Edit)
 End Function
```

In C#:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
    dynamic Model2Edit = Map2Model(GetData(id, WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)));
    return View(Model2Edit);
    }
```

VS.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    EntityModel TheData = new EntityModel();
    int UserID = 0;
    Model Model2Edit = new Model();

    UserID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
    TheData = GetData(id, UserID);
    Model2Edit = Map2Model(TheData);

    return View(Model2Edit);
}
```

Aside from whether or not it is bad practice, I want my code to be readable.  I feel naming the functions descriptively should make it easy enough to follow.

**EDIT** Fixed my title

**EDIT 2** Further refined the question.

**EDIT 3** Added C# code

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Are you asking whether it's good practice for one function to invoke another function?  If so the answer is of course...don't you do that all the time?

Comment: Are asking is it bad practice to call a method in another method? Of course it's not bad practice! How could you possibly program anything without calling methods!

Comment: as opposed to what alternative?

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes - since I'm only using the variables once, why declare new variables when I could just use the return values in the function calls parameter list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming your exact question is:

> Is it considered bad practice to call a function within the parameter list of another function call :
>
> ```
>                                        V---------------------------------------V
> Dim Model2Edit = Map2Model(GetData(id, WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)))
> ```

No, since that's the only place you use the value that's perfectly fine.  If you ever re-used the value then obviously it would be better to keep the reference rather than making the function call again.

Some other things to consider:

- Does it make the function call unneccessarily long?
- Would the call ever throw an exception that you'd want to handle?
- Does the call return a disposable object that you'd want to wrap in a `using` block?

If you want a true litmus test have someone else look at the code and see if they have a hard time understanding what the intent is.

Comment: ahhh, that's what the question is....

Comment: Good job decrypting the question

Comment: "Does the call return a disposable object that you'd want to wrap in a using block?" Should I be using "Using" considering the scenario?

Comment: @merlot No - GetUserId returns a string which does not need disposal.

Comment: @DStanley GetUserID returns an integer

Comment: @merlot my bad - I looked at the  signature wrong.  Still, no `using` needed for that.

Answer (score 1):

Start by making some variables:

```
Dim name = User.Identity.Name
Dim User = WebSecurity.GetUserId(name)
Dim Data = GetData(id, User)
Dim Model2Edit = Map2Model(Data)
Return View(Model2Edit)
```

Then identify parts used in other parts of your program like getting the user, and start refactoring:

```
Dim User = GetUser() -> introduce a new function
Dim Data = GetData(id, User)
Dim Model2Edit = Map2Model(Data)
Return View(Model2Edit)
```

This is just a start in refactoring and making it more readable.